# HTML form populated by Database search

Tags: javascript, html, database, express

Currently, I have a simple Javascript and HTML form page that I use to capture data and post it to the database. I have a page that displays but I was wondering if there was a way I could add a search button to the Index.html and load the data onto the form.

Current code that loads data from the to a non-editable page:

```
const DB = express.Router();
const db = require('./db.js');

DB.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    db.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        connection.query(`select * from table order by id DESC limit 15;`,
            (err, table) => {
                connection.release();
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(400).send(`Something went wrong, we are working on it`)
                }
                res.status(200).send(table)
            });
    });
});

DB.get('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    const id = req.params.id
    db.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        connection.query(`select * from table where id like ?;`,
            id, (err, data) => {
                connection.release();
                if (err || data.length === 0) {
                    console.log(`'id Requested': ${id}`);
                    return res.status(404).send(`id (${id}) not found`);
                }
                console.log(`id Requested: ${id}`);
                console.log('id Data:');
                console.log(data);
                res.status(200).send(data)
            });
    });
});

module.exports = DB;
```

I would like for the results of this to get loaded into the HTML form. I'm thinking that instead of using this as a hostname/data I could turn it into a search button-based off the id field and populate subsequent data. It is the same form that currently Posts this data to the Database so I think this hopefully wont be too hard.

Comment: Sure, that's possible.

Comment: Do you have any tutorials I could look at?